# Specify namespace when using "render" with an object in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, render

So, you can do something like that in rails:

```
@features.each do |feature|
    render feature
end
```

and it will look for a partial called `_feature.html.erb` in the `views/features` folder, based on the class name.

But what if features are in a cms namespace?
Is it possible to specify the namespace? Doing something like this (it doesnt work, obviously)

```
render [:cms, feature]
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to be more explicit:

```
render :partial => '/cms/feature', :object => feature
```

This will render the 'app/views/cms/_feature.html.erb' partial with the object being 'feature'.

Comment: Ok, but if I wanted to do that, I would just do `render "/cms/feature", :feature => feature`, which is nicer in my opinion :)

Comment: That's up to you, but there isn't a compact format like [:cms, feature]. You have to be more explicit. you could also create a helper of your own to do the same thing though.

Comment: Ok :) Maybe I'll write a helper.